# How does display chart javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

i'm working on web application and i need to use library "Chart.js".I'm testing the code on "jsfiddle" and i don't know why this doesn't work!
Thanks for help.
`<body>
<canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
</body>`
var data = {

```
                labels: ["Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", "Luglio", "Agosto"], 
                datasets: [ 
                    { 
                        label: "Temperature 2013", 
                        fillColor: "rgba(99,240,220,0.2)", 
                        strokeColor: "rgba(99,240,220,1)", 
                        pointColor: "rgba(99,240,220,1)", 
                        pointStrokeColor: "#fff", 
                        pointHighlightFill: "#fff", 
                        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)", 
                        data: [8, 11, 18, 22, 24, 26, 34, 39] 
                    }, 
                    { 
                        label: "Temperature 2014", 
                        fillColor: "rgba(205,99,151,0.2)", 
                        strokeColor: "rgba(205,99,151,1)", 
                        pointColor: "rgba(205,99,151,1)", 
                        pointStrokeColor: "#fff", 
                        pointHighlightFill: "#fff", 
                        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)", 
                        data: [16, 18, 22, 24, 26, 28, 32, 36] 
                    } 
                ] 
            };
```

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
   var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);`[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tx2bLpod/4/)

Comment: Downvoted and voted to close as off-topic because no code included. [The message](http://i.stack.imgur.com/u395R.png) has clearly told you to do that.

Comment: My bad,Just a mistake..keep calm bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed both links to https and changed this

```
   var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);

 // to this
   var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data
});
```

The [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/k9y1a2nL/) renders two lines.

Comment: The cause is the https instead of http:  `http://jsfiddle.net/k9y1a2nL/` should work.

Comment: If you find my reply usefull you can upvote it. If i answered your question you can accept it, so that others can see that your question was answered. If you need more info please add a comment and i will try to help.